# Is there is a different way to connect to Microsoft SQL Server with sequelize?

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I want to connect to Microsoft SQL Server with Sequelize in node js.
When I tried to connect, I get this error in the console:

> Error:SequelizeConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)

Could you please help to fix this error, because I have looked in many websites and the error continues to show up.

This is my code:

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({path:'.env'})

const db = new Sequelize(process.env.BD_NOMBRE,process.env.BD_USUARIO,process.env.BD_PASSWORD,{
    host: process.env.BD_HOST,
    port: process.env.BD_PORT,
    dialect: 'mssql',

    define:{
        timestamps: 0
    },
    pool:{
        max:5,
        min:0,
        acquire:30000,
        idle:10000
    },
    operatorsAliases:0
});

export default db;
```

Comment: Is your server set up to accept TCP/IP connections?

Comment: yes, accept TCP/IP connections

Comment: Do you have an instance of SQL Server installed and running? Is it actually listening on TCP port 1433? e.g.: if it's an Express edition of SQL Server it likely won't be listening on TCP ports by default, and enabling the TCP/IP protocol for it defaults to listening on a random high-numbered port.

Comment: Is this Python script running in a Docker container or a VS Code dev container? Containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs and, from a networking perspective, `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` all refer to the container itself. When running in a container have you tried using `host.docker.internal` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes  } = require("sequelize"); <== you need this part
const tedious =  require('tedious');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_MSSQL, process.env.USER_MSSQL, process.env.PASSWORD_MSSQL, {
  host: process.env.HOST_MSSQL,
  dialect: "mssql",
  dialectModule: tedious, <== you need this part
  operatorsAliases: 0,
  logging: false,
  port: process.env.PORT_MSSQL,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000,
    connectTimeout: 20000,
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    options: { 
      encrypt: false,
      "requestTimeout": 300000, 
      instanceName: process.env.INSTANCENAME_MSSQL
    },
    useUTC: false,
    timezone: "+07:00"
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**